# Move to a Location Programatically in "react-map-gl" using latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation, mapbox, react-map-gl

Is there any way to programmatically move to a location in react-map-gl
I have tried many ways but nothing works

*I'm using vite as my build tool*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> programmatically move to a location

if you mean move smoothly from one to another location by this, checkout `flyTo()` you can find an example [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/flyto/)

Answer (score 0):

use `.flyto()` method

For an example, have a look at ["Camera Transition"](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/examples/viewport-animation) on react-map-gl's docs